# Add second page in existing crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i have created a crystal report, it was working successfully, but i want to add a second page of that report. Second page is not going to contain any database fields, i am going to display a terms & condition of the organization. i have tried to add the second page, while it running it shows some data from 1st page also. So please let me know how to do this..

Comment: post an image of your report's design

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using "Section" for displaying "*Terms and Conditions*", select "**New Page After**" for that section under "Section Expert" option.

Comment: i have tried that friend, page has come, but it contains some data of 1st page.

Answer (score 0):

I never manage to solve it that way, instead, I use a [subreport](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/772444/How-do-I-display-two-different-query-results-in-tw)

Comment: can you elaborate on this answer without just linking to external sources? You can leave the link in place, but a bit more is needed.